# can not set cookie for whole of domain from subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

Here is my code:

```
setcookie('set_User',$_POST['email'],time()+3600,'/','.mydomain.com');
```

I also tried the opposite, I mean setting cookie for whole domain from main domain, but in both of cases cookies are only available at where which they are created not other subdomains or the main domain if they are sent from subdomains.
any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't set an POST variable directly to your cookie ;) filter them before otherwise anyone can set cookies for you over your form.

Comment: it uses a safe loop using google ReCaptcha, it's only this piece of my code which doesn't work.
By the way, thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Try without the first dot = `mydomain.com` with new browser

Comment: @Croises I tried it. in main domain I can set the cookie, but it doesn't appear on sub domains. the funny fact is that I can omit the cookie which is created in main domain from subdomain.